# How to add a UIView at top of whole app that pushes every screen design to downward

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiview

I am tring to add a UIView at top of the app when internet is not available. I am using this code that works fine too.

```
let currentWindow: UIWindow? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
self.myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: currentWindow?.frame.size.width ?? 620 , height: newSafeArea.bottom + 35))
currentWindow?.addSubview(self.myView)
```

But the main problem with this code it, I want to add it also the screen should push downward as per images below.

P.S: This will be added on Window object and it needs to stay on every screen.

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**

[image: After]

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to create the view. Constrain to the view itself. Set its size to `.zero` and when it needs to be displayed then change its size. Alternatively, you can use a stack view and add the view to that.

Comment: How it will solver the problem of push down all screen content ?

Comment: If you have proper constraints setup then it will set itself to the label's size. Meaning it will push the rest downwards.

Comment: Dear i thin you are not understanding the problem, This UIView is added on UIWindow? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow and it will retain on every screen because its added on Window. How this will push down the contraints of UIViewControllers ?

Answer (score 0):

There are few workarounds for that. You can simply resize the constant of the top constraint of the view from 0 to desired height of alert or vice versa upon network changes. Then add the alert in the App Delegate.

Comment: How can you resize every screen's constraints ? I have mentioned above we are adding this to Window and every ViewController should adjust correspondingly!

Comment: This is not possible to manipulate key window's frame to bring the screen down for the alert. It may sound hopeless but this is the way it is

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Muzamil but I guess we can still achieve this without adding so many views in every controller, I want to achieve this reusability and generic code. Let's hope a better idea from anyone else. Thanks again for your time

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding additional safe area insets

```
var newSafeArea = UIEdgeInsets()
newSafeArea.top += 50
self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = newSafeArea
```

If you need to do this for all viewcontrollers, your best bet is to have them all sub class from one superclass, then do this update on that when the banner view should appear

Here's the relevant documentation
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area